# WCF Host with 2 services - a few questions

Tags: wcf, windows-services

My idea will be to have a Windows Service that will host 2 WCF services.

**WCF Service A** will be for clients that want to access the database, and perform CRUD operations on it. It will expose operations like 'GetProducts' and 'AddProduct'.

**WCF service B** will be for a WPF 'admin' console, that will connect to the service, and will be able to view which client applications are connected to **WCF Service A**, and also it would expose operations for disconnecting clients from the service, and viewing what actions that client have performed.

My questions are:

**Question 1)** In order to maintain a list of clients that are connected to **WCF Service A** - I will probably need in the service A's instance some kind of list with the names of the clients (each client will have a unique name). Does this mean that I need to create **WCF Service A** using the 'Single Instance' mode (otherwise each client will spawn it's own instance of the service with a list of clients having only 1 client).
Or is a better approach to put the list of clients in some static class outside of **WCF Service A** that all the instances will use (using locks maybe?)

**Question 2)** Is there any smart way of designing both services in some 'manager' container?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single service with two endpoints for the two contracts (standard and admin). You can apply different security to the two endpoints.

If you keep the list of currently connected users as a singleton it can be updated and read from from either endpoint without having to use InstanceContextMode to control it. Just remember that you will most likely be having multiple threads trying to manipulate the singleton and so you will have to ensure that you use thread synchronization when accessing it